# i haven't asked for an argument in my code,but then also its saying "all( ) requires exactly 1 argument,0 given " and i dont know what shoul i do

Tags: python, function, class, oop

```
class alphabet():
    def all():
        start=str(input('enter the alphabet you want to start with'))
        end=str(input('enter the alphabet you want to end with'))``
        for j in range (0,25):
            if start==chr(65+j):
            start=65+j
        for k in range(1,25):
            if end==chr(65+k):
                end=65+k
        for i in range (start,end):
            print(chr(i))
    
alphabet(all())
```

please solve the error as quick as possible
i am trying to make a class "alphabets " in which i am def a function named 'all' which will write alphabets starting and ending on users input

Comment: `def all(self):` is what is needed in class functions

Comment: You're not calling `alphabet.all()`, you're calling the built-in top-level function named `all()`.

Comment: @Cap10 - you dont need the class `alphabet` here. Remove it. Rename the `all` function and use it.

Comment: Another tip, consider using ```ord("A")``` instead of ```65```. Magic numbers obfuscate what your purpose is.

Comment: @Barmar sorry you all !! I was earlier trying to make my own class which had a function to write alphabets from 'user input ' to ' user input', i wasn't clear  about "classes" that time so i didn't use 'self' .BTW  can anybody give the code for building my desired function?

Comment: @depperm sorry you all !! I was earlier trying to make my own class which had a function to write alphabets from 'user input ' to ' user input', i wasn't clear  about "classes" that time so i didn't use 'self' .BTW  can anybody give the code for building my desired function?

Comment: @balderman sorry you all !! I was earlier trying to make my own class which had a function to write alphabets from 'user input ' to ' user input', i wasn't clear  about "classes" that time so i didn't use 'self' .BTW  can anybody give the code for building my desired function?

Comment: @sj95126 sorry you all !! I was earlier trying to make my own class which had a function to write alphabets from 'user input ' to ' user input', i wasn't clear  about "classes" that time so i didn't use 'self' .BTW  can anybody give the code for building my desired function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this code.

- `alphabet(all())` does not do what you are expecting. Calling the class `alphabet()` creates an object instance of the class. In this case you are creating an instance and passing the `all()` as an argument.
- `all` is a built-in python function that expects at least one argument. That is the source of your error. You should always avoid defining functions with the name of python built-in functions.

I would suggest to just create a function performing the task you need to do. If you need it to be a class method, this is the format you should be using:

```
class MyClass:
   '''A minimal class example.'''
   def my_method(self):
      '''A minimal method example'''
      # my code here
```

Then you call the method by doing:

```
my_class_instance = MyClass()
my_class_instance.my_method()  # calls the method
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `all`. It is a builtin reserved function is python. Rename it.

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp).

Comment: There's more to the problem than just this.

Comment: @Barmar I am aware .. Lets take them one by one. See my comments.